# redis memory grows infi

Tags: memory, elasticsearch, redis, monitoring, logstash

It seams that the memory of elasticsearch grow infinity, and environment virables ES_MIN_MEM and ES_MAX_MEM doesn't function well. If I found what's going wrong, I'll come back to modify this issue.

I found I make a mistake perhaps. If the logs is not too much, logstash will pop from the list and delete the item. But if logstash or elasticsearch is blocked, then the length of redis key grow infinity. Thanks for your help, this question may be closed, I think.

The following are the original question:

When I use static key(not use %{type} and so on) at the shipper node, the length of the key will grow larger and larger from when we start the monitoring system. But in redis, a general method to removed outdated logs is to set TTL for different keys. So Can we remove the earlier logs under the same key while keep the later ones. 
Or we have other ways to use redis as the cache and avoid memory overflow? Thank you!
The following is my configuration files:

file:shipper.conf

```
input {
    file {
        type => "ceph-daemons"
        path => "/var/log/ceph/ceph-*.log"
        start_position => "end"
    }
    file {
        type => "ceph-activity"
        path => "/var/log/ceph/ceph.log"
        start_position => "end"
    }
    file {
        type => "nova"
        path => "/var/log/nova/*.log"
        start_position => "end"
    }
}
output {
    stdout{ }
    redis {
        host => "10.1.0.154"
        data_type => "list"
        key => "logstash"
    }
}
```

file:central.conf

```
input {
    redis {
        host => "10.1.0.154"
        type => "redis-input"
        data_type => "list"
        key => "logstash"
    }
}
output {
    stdout{ }
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "logstash"
    }
}
```

I found the following in logstash docs:

```
data_type
Value can be any of: "list", "channel", "pattern_channel"
There is no default value for this setting.
Specify either list or channel. If redis\_type is list, then we will BLPOP the key. If redis\_type is channel, then we will SUBSCRIBE to the key. If redis\_type is pattern_channel, then we will PSUBSCRIBE to the key. TODO: change required to true
```

And in redis docs:

```
When BLPOP returns an element to the client, it also removes the element from the list. This means that the element only exists in the context of the client: if the client crashes while processing the returned element, it is lost forever.
```

So am I wrong when reading these docs?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set an expire to elements of a list, and expiring the key won't help you in this case. If you want to trim the number of elements in the list, check the [TRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim) command.

Comment: Is there any way to build "logstash + redis" system that could solve this problem without manually decrease the redis' memory usage? What is the general method?

I know we can use different key according to the dynamic names such as "%{type}" and so on. But how could the input part on the central node know about it?